# Creating view in advance in Flex mobile app

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

In my Flex mobile application, I have `ViewNavigator` and three `Views`.

As it is very important for final user to see the second view without a delay, I would like it to be created in advance (e.g. right after the first one is created).

Is it possible to achieve it with Flex mobile?

Answer (score 0):

View extends SkinnableContainer which has a property "creationPolicy".

```
view.creationPolicy = "all";
```